# java.lang.RuntimeException: Adding window failed please give me solution

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

from two days i has been find the solution for this exception please anybody can give solution for this problem  . in this current activity we used the recyclerview 1000+ items .

java.lang.RuntimeException: Adding window failed 
Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died

this is  constructor of recycler Adapter class

```
 Recycler_Adapter_one_line(Context context, Activity activity, FragmentManager fragmentManager,SQLiteDatabase database,View view){
        this.context=context;
        dataBinder.quetion_list();
        this.activity=activity;
        this.fragmentManager=fragmentManager;
        this.database=database;
        this.view=view;
    }
```

given code is my OnCreateViewHolder method

```
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public View_holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater l=LayoutInflater.from(context);
      View v=  l.inflate(R.layout.recycler_adapter_one_line_inflater,parent,false);
        final View_holder holder=new View_holder(v);
        final ImageView img_download=v.findViewById(R.id.download);
        final ImageView img_favourite=v.findViewById(R.id.img_favourite);
        img_download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dataBinder.getAnim(context,img_download);
                Answer_Bottom_sheet sheet=new Answer_Bottom_sheet(holder.getAdapterPosition(),dataBinder);
                sheet.show(fragmentManager,"ajay");
            }
        });
        img_favourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Snackbar.make(view,"Quetion added to favorite...",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Check out", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                          Intent i=new Intent(context,Favorite_quetion_activity.class);
                          context.startActivity(i);
                    }
                }).show();
                dataBinder.getAnim(context,img_favourite);
                try {
                    ArrayList<Integer> arr=new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    Cursor cursor =database.query("FAVOURITE_TABLE",null,null,null,null,null,null);
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                        arr.add(cursor.getInt(0));
                    }
                    if(arr.isEmpty()){
                        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
                        values.put("val",holder.getAdapterPosition());
                        database.insert("FAVOURITE_TABLE",null,values);
                        arr.clear();
                    }
                    if(!arr.isEmpty()) {
                      if(!arr.contains(holder.getAdapterPosition())){
                          ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
                          values.put("val",holder.getAdapterPosition());
                          database.insert("FAVOURITE_TABLE",null,values);
                          arr.clear();
                      }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                         Toast.makeText(context,""+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        return holder;
    }
```

following code of OnCreateViewHolder method

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull View_holder holder, int position) {
        try {
            ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Cursor cursor = database.query("FAVOURITE_TABLE", null, null, null, null, null, null);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                arr.add(cursor.getInt(0));
            }
            if (arr.contains(position)) {
                holder.img_favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp);
            } else if (!arr.contains(position)) {
                holder.img_favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_white_24dp);
            }
            holder.txt_sr.setText(Integer.toString(position + 1));
            holder.txt_quetion.setText(dataBinder.arr_quaetion_list.get(position));
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(context,""+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

following code of subclass of ViewHolder

```
class View_holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
         TextView txt_sr,txt_quetion;
         CardView cardView;
         ImageView img_favourite;
        public View_holder(@NonNull View
                                   itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            try{
            txt_sr=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_sr);
            txt_quetion=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_quetion);
            cardView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
            img_favourite=itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_favourite);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(context,""+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

logcat showing me following Exception

exception no:-1

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
    at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:321)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:3109)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2851)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2404)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1437)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6886)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1029)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:841)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:772)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1015)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

Exception no :- 2

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Adding window failed
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:769)
                    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
                    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
                    at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:500)
                    at android.widget.Toast$TN$1.handleMessage(Toast.java:404)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                 Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
                    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:776)
                    at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay(IWindowSession.java:801)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:757)
                    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)

                    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94) 
                    at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:500) 
                    at android.widget.Toast$TN$1.handleMessage(Toast.java:404) 
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651) 
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)

                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

Comment: Are you trying fetch remote data to be injected in the viewHolders? Also please add your recyclerView instance code and the recycler view adapter code along with the viewholder layout and class files. The more context you will give us the faster we will be able to solve it.

Comment: give me some more clear ideas i'm junior developer plase sir this is very big problem for me ....in this problem actully happening when we are openig app after few minute leter my app automaticaly exit and showing me this following exception

Comment: Looks like a Deserialization error where the remote response is not getting correct deserialized or parcelized over the network. Take a look at your model classes for the response or the data that you are putting in your recyclerView Adapter.

Comment: here  added our recyclerView Code

Comment: plase sir give me some solution

Comment: Please, sir, give us a minimal reproducible example if you want help.

Comment: sir i dont know what happening runtime my app automatically exit . below showing all code of my recyclerView adapter

Comment: my app directly not exit some minutes later it dead automatically